# Merge std::unordered_map iteratively

Tags: c++, algorithm, merge, c++17, unordered-map

I have a list of nodes that each decompose into more nodes. For example

- Node0 = w01 * Node1 + w02 * Node2 + w03 * Node3
- Node1 = w12 * Node2 + w14 * Node4

Therefore, we have Node0 = w01*w12 * Node2 + w03 * Node3 + w01*w14 Node4.

---

My C++ code for performing the above aggregation/decomposition/merging for a given set of weight decompositions looks as follows. However, I feel there are a lot of optimisations to be made. To name just one, I am looping over the keys of `topWeights` and collect them in `topNodeNames`, which seems terribly inefficient.

Are there any STL algorithms that could help me speed this up, and possibly avoid unnecessary copying?

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T, class U> using umap = std::unordered_map<T, U>;


umap<std::string, double> getWeights(const std::string& nodeName, const umap<std::string, umap<std::string, double>>& weightTrees)
{
    const auto it = weightTrees.find(nodeName);
    if (it == weightTrees.end())
        return umap<std::string, double>();

    umap<std::string, double> topWeights = it->second;
    std::vector<std::string> topNodeNames;

    for (const auto& kv : topWeights)
        topNodeNames.push_back(kv.first);

    for (const std::string& topNodeName : topNodeNames)
    {
        umap<std::string, double> subWeights = getWeights(topNodeName, weightTrees);
        if (subWeights.size() > 0)
        {
            const double topWeight = topWeights[topNodeName];
            topWeights.erase(topNodeName);
            for (const auto& subWeight : subWeights)
            {
                const auto it = topWeights.find(subWeight.first);
                if (it == topWeights.end())
                    topWeights[subWeight.first] = topWeight * subWeight.second;
                else
                    it->second += topWeight * subWeight.second;
            }
        }
    }

    return topWeights;
}


int main()
{
    umap<std::string, umap<std::string, double>> weightTrees = {{ "Node0", {{ "Node1",0.5 },{ "Node2",0.3 },{ "Node3",0.2 }} },
                                                                { "Node1", {{ "Node2",0.1 },{ "Node4",0.9 }} }};

    umap<std::string, double> w = getWeights("Node0", weightTrees); // gives {Node2: 0.35, Node3: 0.20, Node4: 0.45}
}
```

Comment: What happens in case of circular dependencies (I assume there are none)? Does your real use case have many common nodes between different branches?

Comment: Circular dependencies should never happen (in a real case scenario). But I agree, it'd be good so have some sort of security check for this. As for question 2, it really can vary.

Comment: There is no limit as to how many levels. One node can decompose into another, that decomposes into another, that decomposes into two, etc.

Comment: Is there already an order to the nodes? (I.e. `NodeN` never depends on nodes `NodeK` with `K < N`)? Edit: Yeah, I misunderstood the specification when I asked the previous question.

Comment: @MaxLanghof No, you may as well call the nodes: ABC, Node23, Server10, TestNode, etc.

Comment: Ok, I didn't mean in terms of literal names but I assume this doesn't change the answer.

Comment: "I feel there are a lot of optimisations to be made" -- stop right there! Before you even think about optimizing anything, you need to be able to measure the results of your efforts, so define a set of benchmarks that mimick actual use cases. Any other optimization attempt is premature.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't think improving your O(N!) algorithm counts as premature optimization. At least for any non-trivial input sizes.

Comment: Well, that requires knowing the asymptotic complexity of your algorithm first, so that may be a well-informed decision. Still, my point holds that with guessing, you make a bad decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are recursing for **every** node to **every** subnode, which is generally highly redundant. One way to avoid this would be to introduce an order on the node names, where "higher" nodes depend only on "lower" nodes and then calculate them in reverse order (for each node you'll already know all child weights exactly). However, I don't think there are `std` algorithms that will find this order for you because you can't transiently determine node dependencies cheaply ("does node X depend on node Y? If it's not directly, we might have to search the entire tree...").

So, you could just go the dynamic programming route and store nodes that you have fully calculated somewhere. Or even better - you could just flatten the entire tree down to leaf-only weights as you traverse it. As long as you retain the flattening throughout the recursion, this is actually quite elegant in recursive form:

```
using NodeWeights = std::unordered_map<std::string, double>;
using NonLeaves = std::unordered_map<std::string, NodeWeights>;

// Modifies the tree so that the given root has no non-leaf children.
void flattenTree(std::string root, NonLeaves& toFlatten)
{
    auto rootIt = toFlatten.find(root);
    if (rootIt == toFlatten.end())
        return;

    NodeWeights& rootWeights = rootIt->second;

    NodeWeights leafOnlyWeights;

    for (auto kvp : rootWeights)
    {
        const std::string& childRoot = kvp.first;
        double childWeight = kvp.second;

        std::cout << "Checking child " << childRoot << std::endl;

        // If the graph is indeed acyclic, then the root kvp here is untouched
        // by this call (and thus references to it are not invalidated).
        flattenTree(childRoot, toFlatten);

        auto childIt = toFlatten.find(childRoot);

        // The child is a leaf after flattening: Do not modify anything.
        if (childIt == toFlatten.end())
        {
            leafOnlyWeights[childRoot] = childWeight;
            continue;
        }

        // Child is still not a leaf (but all its children are now leaves):
        // Redistribute its weight among our other child weights.
        const NodeWeights& leafWeights = childIt->second;
        for (auto leafKvp : leafWeights)
            leafOnlyWeights[leafKvp.first] += childWeight * leafKvp.second;
    }

    rootWeights = leafOnlyWeights;
}

int main()
{
    umap<std::string, umap<std::string, double>> weightTrees = {{ "Node0", {{ "Node1",0.5 },{ "Node2",0.3 },{ "Node3",0.2 }} },
                                                                { "Node1", {{ "Node2",0.1 },{ "Node4",0.9 }} }};

    auto flattenedTree = weightTrees;
    flattenTree("Node0", flattenedTree);

    umap<std::string, double> w = flattenedTree["Node0"]; // Should give {Node2: 0.35, Node3: 0.20, Node4: 0.45}

    for (auto kvp : w)
      std::cout << kvp.first << ": " << kvp.second << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dfbe84be58ebc9e)

Since each node is flattened at most once, you cannot run into the exponential runtime your original algorithm has.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems I'll have to copy the entire tree via `auto flattenedTree = weightTrees;` each time I do a decomposition? What if `weightTrees` is very large? Or what if the decompositions are trivial (or very simple), then I'll still have to copy the entire tree first?

Comment: This is just a straightforward implementation of the idea. If you don't need to keep the original then this is better. If you need to keep it but want to avoid the deep copy first then you may implement this in a way where the additional storage only stores leaf-only representations as you find them instead of starting with the full tree.

Comment: Let me have a think. Thanks!

Comment: I also just realized there's still a mistake in there due to the way unordered map erase interacts with the added elements. Let me fix it. Edit: Fixed.

Comment: Take a look at the fixed version for what I alluded to earlier: You could essentially store all the calculated `leafOnlyWeights` instead of modifying the original (and check those before the original). But this may also have uncanny growth because you have to retain all leaf-only representations. I doubt there's an escape from the memory vs speed tradeoff here.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing a topological sort followed by a dynamic programming algorithm.  [Standard versions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/) of a topological sort using Khan's algorithm take time `O(V+E)`.  (If that link goes stale, you can just use Google to find another.)  In your case `V` is the number of nodes, and `E` is the number of terms that appear in all of your expressions.

If that sort fails, then you have found a circular dependency.  Discovering it that way is better than having your code blow up.

Once you have that sort, then going from the end to the front with DP is very straightforward.

Also if you're truly concerned with performance, one of your performance constraints is that every operation is done using string comparisons.  Throwing around lots of strings is easy and convenient - that's why scripting languages do it all the time.  However it is also slow.  I have found it worthwhile in the past to create a lookup structure that turns strings into indexes before entering performance critical code, then be throwing around some type of `int` instead of a string.  And then at the end use the lookup to turn it back into strings.

Comment: Could you explain your last point in more detail? Doesn't `unordered_map` use an internal hash structure to store/look up keys? And do you have examples on what a set-up for your "standard" lookup-up structure would look like (in C++)?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX In C, a string is an array of bytes and every string operation requires looping over them.  In C++ a string is a complex data structure, and string operations may require following a pointer to where it is actually stored followed by looping operations.  By contrast comparing ints is a built-in operation in the CPU.  No pointer.  No variable length loop.  So faster.  And a hash lookup on a string requires a variable length loop on the string to compute the hash, followed by similar loops to see if you found the same one in the hash.  Which is slower than doing hashes on ints.

Comment: As for an implementation, you can simply create a vector of nodes, a lookup map to find the index for a string, and then use the indexes in your code.  However this is not very maintainable for complex code.  In the past I've solved that by creating small classes that have a lookup from `std::string` to the object instance, have a convenience method for taking a string and getting a pointer to the unique object representing that string, and then just use pointers elsewhere.    And now the type system keeps me from mixing up what goes where.